# Recover XFS partition after writing Ubuntu ISO over it

Tags: linux, data-recovery, xfs

I usually write my ISO distros on USB pendrives with USB Writer or "dd" command. Accidentaly, I selected a 1TB HD connected via USB external dock station to write an Ubuntu ISO. ISO was about 2GB, but I noticed my error just after I wrote the ISO to the XFS HD.

So now, my Linux recognizes my 1TB HD like an Ubunto bootable disk, but the XFS filesystem is unnaccesible.

I read here some other XFS repairing cases, but was not the same situation.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It can't be repaired in the real sense but you may want to try file recovery with a software that supports xfs. However,  if this was a system partition, don't waste your time.

Comment: Unfortunately, not a system partition but a data backup, that's why I'm interested in recover the info that IS still there.